# Trying to make form using tabular and underline?

Tags: tables, forms

I am trying to make a form using `\tabular{r l}` and underlined `\hspace` to make lines. I am trying to make the hspace fill the available space using \fill, but it isn't working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Helpdesk ticket}
\author{felixphew}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r l}
Name & \underline{\hspace{\fill}} \\
Ticket No & \underline{\hspace{\fill}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, the underlines don't show up. The results I'm looking for are somewhat similar to [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/557a572bdfb75ebd54bfba87/output/output.pdf?cache_bust=1434083223463&compileGroup=standard&build=14de60566b2) (produced using `9cm` instead of `\fill`), however there should be some way of making the underlines use all available space.

Comment: In this case it is better to simple insert a rule: `\rule{4cm}{.4pt}` (I never remember the order of variables; maybe swap them; one is for length and the other for thickness).

Comment: @Sigur, I can already do that, but I'm looking to have the lines automatically extend to the right length (hence `\fill`)

Comment: Will the form be filled in TeX or only by hand? Do you want to type text above the rule?

Comment: @Sigur Only by hand, otherwise I would be using `hyperref`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this enough to you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Helpdesk ticket}
\author{felixphew}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.2\linewidth} @{}p{.8\linewidth}}
\textbf{Name:} & \hrulefill\\[5pt]
\textbf{Ticket No:} & \hrulefill
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another solution:** if you want to have more flexibility on the lengths you can just change the value for `\firstcol` and then the other will be the difference.

So, suppose that you have to write a field with longer length, just change the length of the 1st column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Helpdesk ticket}
\author{felixphew}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlength{\firstcol}
\newlength{\secondcol}
\setlength{\firstcol}{2cm}
\setlength{\secondcol}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\secondcol}{-\firstcol}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\firstcol} @{}p{\secondcol}}
\textbf{Name:} & \hrulefill\\[5pt]
\textbf{Ticket No:} & \hrulefill
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @felixphew, please, see the other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless, that is to late ... an another solution, slightly simplified from @Sigur answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\title{Helpdesk ticket}
\author{felixphew}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r X}
\textbf{Name:}      &   \hrulefill  \\[5pt]
\textbf{Ticket No:} &   \hrulefill  \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

or a bit more different from @Sigur answer (and less beatifful):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\title{Helpdesk ticket}
\author{felixphew}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r X}
\textbf{Name:}      &       \\      \cline{2-2}
\textbf{Ticket No:} &       \\      \cline{2-2}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good idea to use `tabularx`. Since I rarely type tables I didn't know about this package.

Comment: I liked your calculation of width of columns :-) and idea of use `\hrulefill` didn't cross my mind :-(.

Comment: with my code you can type 2 separated tables with the same length for rules (since they are defined globally). I mean, you can have a kind of break on the table (at least visually).

Answer (score 3):

Well then, maybe I could also show the code that I wrote a good many years ago to cope with a similar problem (slightly re-adapted, actually).  It does not involve `tabular` at all, so feel free to completely ignore this answer.  The point being made is that I needed some (optional) explanatory text below the rules.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter

% Command \fillinline prints a rule with an optional explanatory text underneath.
%
% Usage:
%   \fillinline[<text>]{<width>}
%       Prints a rule of width <width>, with explanatory text <text> underneath.
%       <width> may be equal to \fill.
\newcommand*\fillinline[2][]{%
    \setlength\skip@{#2}%
    \vrule \@height 8mm \@width\z@
    \nobreak \leaders\hrule \@height .2\p@ \hskip\skip@
    \nobreak
    \hskip -\skip@
    \divide\skip@\tw@
    \hskip\skip@
    \makebox[\z@][c]{\raisebox{-1ex}[\z@][\z@]{\tiny #1}}%
    \nobreak\hskip\skip@
    \kern\p@ % in case a punctuation follows
}

% Another simple trick that may be handy:
\newenvironment*{checkboxitemize}
    {\itemize[label=$\Box$, leftmargin=*]} % or set labelindent as well
    {\enditemize}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

The undersigned \fillinline[Surname, Name]{\fill},\linebreak
born in~\fillinline{\fill}
on \fillinline[mm]{6mm}/\fillinline[dd]{6mm}/\fillinline[year]{10mm},\linebreak\space
etc. etc.

Payment method:
\begin{checkboxitemize}
    \item  Cheque

    \item  Credit card

    \item  \ldots
\end{checkboxitemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above code]