# Rubber width `\parbox`

Tags: boxes

I am trying to create a rubber width `\parbox` in LaTeX so that the whole line will be evenly filled. It is for creating a mad-libs style fill in command that will stretch a certain amount of width. I tried the following:

```
\newcommand{\libfillin}[2]
{
    \parbox[t]{#1 plus50pt minus50pt}{
        \rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
        \parbox[t][1pt][b]{\linewidth}{\small \centering
        \emph{#2}}\vspace{2pt}\hfill\\
    }
}
```

However, this results in the text `plus50pt` `minus50pt` being printed and invalid width for the parboxes. How might I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole line will be evenly filled"? Horizontally? Then you could/should just use `\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{...}`.

Comment: So that the text will remain justified.

Comment: your question is completely unclear however perhaps the `varwidth` environment from the package of that name is what you are looking for,

Comment: also what effect do you intend `\vspace{2pt}\hfill\\ ` to have?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249896/69818) might be related to your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'd never heard of mad-libs but google leads to Wikipedia that suggests that you want an output like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1{%
\mbox{}%
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\nobreak\leaders\hrule\hskip\wd0 plus 20pt minus 20pt
\nobreak\hskip-.5\wd0 plus -10pt minus -10pt\relax
\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{-7pt}{\small\itshape#1}}%
\nobreak\hskip.5\wd0 plus 10pt minus 10pt\relax\kern0pt
}

\begin{document}

\linespread{4}

\zz{exclamation}! he said \zz{adverb} as he jumped into his convertible
\zz{noun}  and drove off with his \zz{adjective} wife.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is OK, however there is no way to specify the approximate length (or relative length) of the line. For example, "reason" is a short word, but may require a lot of space to write in.

Comment: @smpl I take the approximate length from the length of the "classification" at full size (the `\setbox0\hbox{#1}` at the start, you could have an extra argument that put the _answer_ in there instead then it would use the length of that. or make the extra argument a length and use that instead of `\wd0` in the leader and hskips.

Comment: `\nobreak` before the first `\leaders` prevent a line break at this place, but the line break might be at the start of the space before, then the `\leaders` gets discarded. Something like `\null` before the `\leaders` prevents this.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes thanks I switched to `\mbox`